# Grouping and Ordering Columns in Sql

Tags: sql

I'm running into an issue that I would expect to be easy enough to figure out but for some reason I can't. I have a three column dataset which is made up of the state, county and population. In SQL, I would like to sum the total people by State and County, I would then like to group by State and County and order by Total People in descending order. This is simple enough, except I would like my dataset to first group by state and county then order, meaning if State A County A has the most Total People then all State A rows will be grouped together first.

```
    Select State, County, sum(Total_Population) as tot_pop
        from state_county_2
        group by state, county
        order by tot_pop desc, state,county ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions in the `order by`:

```
Select State, County, sum(Total_Population) as tot_pop
from state_county_2
group by state, county
order by max(tot_pop) over (partition by state) desc,
         state, tot_pop desc, county;
```